# infinite sum of harmonic number powers $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{H_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

I am looking for a simplified form of the infinite sum of harmonic exponentials

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{H_n}
= 1 + x + x^{3/2} + x^{11/6} + x^{25/12} + x^{137/60} + x^{49/20} + \ldots\\
=1+x\left(
1+x^{1/2}\left(
1+x^{1/3}\left(
1+x^{1/4}\left(
1+x^{1/5}\left(
1+x^{1/6}\left(
1+\ldots
\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)
$$
for $x\in[0,1/e)$.

Can it be reduced to a standard special function?

### Update: a stable way of calculating $f(x)$ numerically

Inspired by [Claude Leibovici's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3995537/632893), we write
$$
f(x) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{\gamma+\log(n)} - \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[x^{\gamma+\log(n)}-x^{H_n}\right]}_{g(x)}\\
= 1+x^{\gamma}\zeta[-\log(x)]-g(x)
$$
with $g(x)$ converging rapidly on the entire interval $x\in[0,1/e]$ (and beyond) without singularities:

[image]

Specifically,
$$
g(1/e) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{n}-e^{-H_n}\right]
\approx 0.35370447459102146589\ldots\\
g'(1/e) \approx 0.38530115152397563963\ldots\\
g''(1/e) \approx -0.82751608018475931083\ldots
$$
give the approximate series expansion of $f(x)$ around $x=1/e$,
$$
f(x) \approx
\frac{e^{-\gamma-1}}{1/e-x}
+ 0.36556578362553594918\ldots
+ (1/e-x)\cdot0.11500038261356357678\ldots
+ (1/e-x)^2\cdot0.11786065053337882776\ldots
+O[(1/e-x)^3]
$$

Unfortunately, neither [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) nor [AskConstants](http://math.hawaii.edu/%7Edale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html) recognize any of these numbers.

Comment: I highly doubt that, but it's interesting to look for some other ways to write this function

Comment: $H_n\sim \frac{1}{2 n}+\log n+\gamma$ as $n\to\infty$ if you want an approximation

Comment: The behaviour near $x=1/e$ is $$
f(x) =  - \frac{{x^\gamma  }}{{\log x + 1}} + \mathcal{O}(1).
$$

Comment: From @Gary's estimate $f(x) \sim e^{-\gamma}/(1 - ex) + O(1)$ near $1/e$.

Comment: And based on the numerical work folks have done it looks like we might guess at the constant term: $f(x) \sim e^{-\gamma}/(1 - ex) + 1/e + O(1 - ex)$.

Comment: Note that $$
1 + x^\gamma  \zeta ( - \log x) = \frac{{e^{ - \gamma } }}{{1 - ex}} + \left( {1 - \frac{{e^{ - \gamma } }}{2}} \right) - e^{ - \gamma } \left( {\frac{{\gamma ^2 }}{2} + \gamma _1  + \frac{1}{{12}}} \right)(1 - ex) + \mathcal{O}((1 - ex)^2 ),
$$ so you have to take this into account when computing the constant term in the expansion of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thus, the constant term will be $$
1 - \frac{{e^{ - \gamma } }}{2} - g\left( {\frac{1}{e}} \right) = 1 - \frac{{e^{ - \gamma } }}{2} - e^{ - \gamma } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{n} - e^{ - \psi (n + 1)} } \right)}  = 0.36556578 \ldots \, .
$$ Note that $1/e = 0.36787944\ldots$.

Comment: The following gives 20 significant digits by just taking 55 terms: $$
g\left( {\frac{1}{e}} \right) = \\ e^{ - \gamma } \left( {\frac{{\pi ^2 }}{{12}} - \frac{5}{{24}}\zeta (3) + \frac{{\pi ^4 }}{{1440}} - \frac{{47}}{{5760}}\zeta (5) + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}\left( {1 - e^{ - \psi (n + 1) + \log n}  - \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{5}{{24n^2 }} - \frac{1}{{16n^3 }} + \frac{{47}}{{5760n^4 }}} \right)} } \right).
$$ The value is $0.35370447459112350610\ldots$.

Comment: Impressive @Gary.

Comment: Thanks @Gary! Inspired by your comments I've updated the question a bit. I disagree with your numerical results though and believe you only got 12 digits correct.

Comment: @Roman You are correct, I recomputed it and got the same value as you did.

Answer (score 4):

As @Raffaele commented, if you use the approximation
$$H_n\sim \log( n)+\gamma$$

Using what you wrote (notice that $H_7=2.59$ while $\log(7)+\gamma=2.52$)
$$f(x)\sim1 + x + x^{3/2} + x^{11/6} + x^{25/12} + x^{137/60} + x^{49/20} +
x^\gamma\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}n^{\log(x)}$$
$$\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}n^{\log(x)}=\zeta (-\log (x))-\sum_{k=1}^6 k^{\log(x)}$$ which converges for $x\lt \frac 1e$.

Let us compare for a few values of $x$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.00 & 1.00000 & 1.00000 \\
 0.02 & 1.02424 & 1.02421 \\
 0.04 & 1.05408 & 1.05391 \\
 0.06 & 1.08957 & 1.08911 \\
 0.08 & 1.13148 & 1.13055 \\
 0.10 & 1.18100 & 1.17937 \\
 0.12 & 1.23976 & 1.23718 \\
 0.14 & 1.30998 & 1.30621 \\
 0.16 & 1.39482 & 1.38955 \\
 0.18 & 1.49874 & 1.49168 \\
 0.20 & 1.62838 & 1.61920 \\
 0.22 & 1.79396 & 1.78233 \\
 0.24 & 2.01210 & 1.99766 \\
 0.26 & 2.31175 & 2.29413 \\
 0.28 & 2.74822 & 2.72704 \\
 0.30 & 3.44199 & 3.41684 \\
 0.32 & 4.71483 & 4.68530 \\
 0.34 & 7.81187 & 7.77753 \\
 0.36 & 26.6198 & 26.5802
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seems to be quite decent.

So, you can write
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{H_n}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}x^{H_n}+x^\gamma\Big[\zeta (-\log (x))-\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} k^{\log(x)}\Big]\tag 1$$

As @Roman commented, if you take a large value of $m$, the asymptotics is
$$f(x)\sim  \sum_{n=0}^{m}x^{H_n}-\frac{m\, x^{\gamma+\log (m)}}{1+\log(x)}$$

**Edit**

Equation $(1)$ can be simplified ; in terms of the  Hurwitz zeta function, it is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{H_n}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}x^{H_n}+x^\gamma \,\zeta (-\log (x),m+1)$$ and expanded as series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}x^{H_n}-x^{\gamma+\log(m)} g(t)\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\log(x)$$
$$g(t)=\frac{m}{t+1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{12 m}-\frac{(t-2) (t-1) t}{720 m^3}+\frac{(t-4)
   (t-3) (t-2) (t-1) t}{30240 m^5}-\frac{(t-6) (t-5) (t-4) (t-3) (t-2) (t-1)
   t}{1209600 m^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^9}\right)$$

Comment: Very nice, thanks Claude! The Hurwitz $\zeta$-function can further be series-expanded and we find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{H_n} \approx \sum_{n=0}^{m}x^{H_n}-\frac{m x^{\gamma+\ln m}}{1+\ln x}$ for large $m$.

Comment: [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238640/26598) for an application of this approximation.

Comment: @Claude, very nice! I'm interested to know how you computed the exact estimates. The series converges very slowly.

Comment: @Aruralreader. Which *estimates* ? Which *series converges very slowly* ? Remember that you cannot compute for $x\geq \frac 1 e$

Comment: @Claude, the numbers you report as the exact values for comparison. How did you compute those?

Comment: @Aruralreader. Numerically untill converge for seven figures.

Comment: Thank you @Claude, I appreciate your guidance. I must be doing something wrong on my side. From the remainder estimate $R_m(x) = m x^{\gamma + \log m}/(1 + \log x)$ with $x = 0.3$, it seems to me I'd need on the order of $m = 10^{30}$ terms in the series to get that kind of accuracy.

Comment: Powerful work Claude! Your answers always impress me.