# convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{\varphi (n)}$ where $\varphi (n)= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have to analyse the convergence and divergence of this serie:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{\varphi(n)} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{for} \hspace{0.5cm} x>0
\end{eqnarray*}
where:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}
\end{eqnarray*}
For this, I take some cases:

---

1. when $x=1$ in this case, I take:
   \begin{eqnarray*}
    \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1^{\varphi(n)}=1
   \end{eqnarray*}
   and, for a reciprocal of a theorem, this serie in this case diverges.

---

2. Where $x>1$, in this case the limit:
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x^{\varphi (n)} = +\infty
   \end{eqnarray*}
   So, we have that serie diverges

---

3. Where $0<x<1$, I noticed that $x^{\varphi(n)}$ es positive and decreasing so I had tried to take by integral test but it's hard for me, cause I don't know how can I evaluate this integral. How can I continued by this way? or if can give me some hint to take this case, I will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Hint, if $x<1$, what classical series converges ? can you majorate $x^{\varphi(n)}$ by the $n-$th term of this series ?

Comment: You have $$\varphi(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} \leq 1+\int_2^n \frac{1}{x} dx = 1 +\log(n) - \log(2).$$ Thus, for large $n$ we have $\varphi(n)\leq (1+\varepsilon) \log(n).$ We could do a similar lower bound. Now use $$x^{(1\pm \varepsilon)\log(n)} = n^{(1\pm \varepsilon)\log(x)}.$$ When will the series over those guys converge? I guess you can finish from here

Comment: Maybe of related interest is [infinite sum of harmonic number powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995401/infinite-sum-of-harmonic-number-powers-sum-n-0-inftyxh-n).